# show X button only when text is entered in the textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am using the plugin available [here](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/clearable-textbox-jquery/) to remove the text in the textbox by clicking on the X button. How do I modify the code so that the X button shows up only when text is entered in the text box?
I tried setting condition on the return starement in JavaScript code: `if ($('#search').val().length != 0)` but it dint work.
Here is the code I tried:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if ($('#search').val().length != 0){
        $('#search').clearable();
        $('.divclearable').show();
    }
    else{
        $('.divclearable').hide();
    }
});
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a `keyup` listener -

```
$(function () {
    $("#search").on("keyup", function() {
        if ($('#search').val().length != 0){
            $('#search').clearable();
            $('.divclearable').show();
        }
        else{
            $('.divclearable').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: @Archer I don't understand it too, an explanation would be great from the downvoter. But that sometimes happens :)

Comment: I think it was the butt hurt guy that deleted his answer because it was pointed out to be wrong.

Comment: @ZoltanToth: your answer looks promising, but unfortunately, it dint work for me. Here is my complete code: https://gist.github.com/dc59408990ebbf17f2d6

Comment: @rad you didn't close all your parenthesis in the JS, also there is no closing `</input>` tag - http://jsfiddle.net/xeadw/

Comment: @ZoltanToth, I fixed the errors that you mentioned. Now, the button shows up when I enter something in the textbox for the first time, when I click on it, the button does not disappear though. And, when I enter some text again, another X button gets appended to the previous one.

Comment: can you reproduce the issue in the JSFiddle I made?

Comment: Here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/xeadw/1/
try clicking on X, it doesnt hide the button.
Also, if you try entering text again and clicking on X, another X button gets appended.

Comment: the plugin itself seems to do exactly what you want - http://jsfiddle.net/xeadw/2/

Comment: Wow! It is amazing the way it is working with just a single line of code! How ever, when I put the code back together, it is not working :( http://jsfiddle.net/xeadw/3/

Comment: Remove the jquery reference from your code or from JSFiddle panels - http://jsfiddle.net/xeadw/4/

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the CSS, it appears that the button is part of the `clearlink` class.

You would simply do `$("a.clearlink").hide()` to hide it.

**This will handle events other than simple key presses**:

```
$('.divclearable > input').change(
    function() 
    {
        if($(this).val().length == 0)
           $(this).closest('a.clearlink').hide();
        else
           $(this).closest('a.clearlink').show();
    }
);
```

Comment: Why `$('.divclearable').change`? Don't you mean `$('.#search').change`, similar to the answer below from 5 minutes ago?

Comment: @Archer Because the CSS on the page of the plug-in lists that as the class name, which would make this function apply to all of the clearable controls. I am also taking into account events such as cut which would clear the box without using a keyup event.

Comment: But the change event doesn't occur on the wrapped div - it occurs on the input **Edit**: Yep - you spotted it too and fixed it :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the jquery change event fires when an element's text is changed by javascript.

You may want to attach a click event to the clear button so it hides itself in addition to clearing the text. I'm not sure if this conflicts with the event handler for the library you are using however...

```
$("#search").change(check_input);
$('.divclearable').click(check_input);
check_input = function(){
    if ($('#search').val().length != 0){
        $('#search').clearable();
        $('.divclearable').show();
    }
    else{
        $('.divclearable').hide();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I will talk with you about the logic, you should do your own implementation:
There is a css class called "clearlink" which displays the close button. modify it and set on of initial values to be: display: none, then in your Jquery code when nyou detect length change supply it with method change display:none to block. or make a copy of clearlink as clearlink1 and change the class name of the element.

Just use the inspect Element feature in your browser.